# C++ - Parameters of a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

If I have a class say

```
class Base {
 public:
  virtual void func() = 0;
};
```

That is the base for two other classes

```
class DerivedA1 : public Base {
 public:
  virtual bool func(string command);
};

class DerivedB1 : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void func();
}

class DerivedA2 : public DerivedA1 {
 public:
  bool func(string command);     //This one implements it differently
};                                 //its base class.
```

Is the above allowed? I declared func() with no parameters but then I'm using it with parameters. I have a similar situation in my code that I can't post because this is it's part of a school assignment, and am getting an error similar to

```
error: no matching function for call to Base::fucn(std::string&)
note: candidate is: virtual bool Base::move();
note: candidate expects 0 arguments, provided  1
```

I want func() to be used differently in its different derived classes. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: No, it isn't allowed. Overrides of `virtual` functions of the base class must have the exact same signature.

Comment: There is a concept called *contravariance* which allows the derived class to change the method's argument (not arbitrarily though), but that does not apply here. You could use *default arguments*: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

Comment: You can make another class for the parameter. virtual void func(MyBaseParemeterClass*) = 0;

Comment: @mike: if default parameters on virtual functions are not identical for all overrides, calling them behaves differently depending on the used type. I find this too brittle and confusing, so I try to avoid default parameters in such situations.

Answer (score 2):

`DerivedA1::func(string)` is *hiding* `Base::func()`. It's allowed, but won't override the behaviour of `Base::func`. clang will warn you about this because it's almost always an error

```
class DerivedA1 : public Base {
 public:
  virtual bool func(string command);
};
```

This is fine:

```
class DerivedB1 : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void func();
}
```

This is overriding `DerivedA1::func(string)`. A virtual function which only exists on a `DervivedA1` interface or something derived from it. It does not exist on `Base`

```
class DerivedA2 : public DerivedA1 {
 public:
  bool func(string command);     //This one implements it differently
};
```